Validation of Area Calculation via Complex Jacobian
Cross-posted on MathOverflow
I want to know whether the following approach and computations are correct for calculating the area of the image of a polynomial under a polynomial map. Here are my thoughts:
I want to estimate the area $ A $ of the image of the unit disk under a polynomial map $z \mapsto p(z) $; I start with using the formula derived from the complex derivative $p'(z) $ of the polynomial, given the mapping's holomorphic (complex-differentiable) nature everywhere in the complex plane.
The area formula using  the complex Jacobian determinant can be written as:
$$
A = \int_{|z| \leq 1} |p'(z)|^2 \, dA
$$
Here, ( dA = r , dr , d\theta ) in polar coordinates, where ( z = r e^{i\theta} ) so that we have :
$$
A =  \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 |p'(re^{i\theta})|^2 r \, dr \, d\theta
$$
where $p'(z) = a_1 + 2a_2 z + \cdots + na_n z^{n-1} .$ Thank you in advance for ny help and comments

Compare with
$$\begin{align}
  &\int _A\sum _k \ a_k \ r^k \ e^{i k \phi } \ 
    (dr+ i \ r\  d\phi)\wedge (dr - i \ r \ d\phi)
\\&  \frac{2}{i} \ \int_A \ \sum_k \ a_k \  r^{k+1}\ e^{i k \phi} \  dr\wedge  d\phi
\\&\frac{2}{i} \  \int _{\partial A} \ \sum _k \  a_k  \ 
   \frac{r(\phi)^{k+2}}{k+2} \ e^{i k \phi } d \phi\end{align}$$
The use of the metric square of the Jacobian in differential forms is a deviation, the wedge products yield the Pfaffian form directly and preserve orientation. There is no scalar product involved in integrals. The algebra behind: The determinant of an antisymmetric matrix is the square of its Pfaffian.
